# Multiple sorting methods failed in single program in java

Tags: java, sorting

My program doesn't show each of the correct list it's being sorted, number of comparison and number of assignment except bubble sorting method. I think I missed to reset the input string but could not figure out the way to reset input.
Is there any way to sort one input in different sorting method.
Here is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Create a program that does head-to-head comparisons between four sorting
 * methods: improved bubble sort; selection sort; insertion sort; and Shell
 * sort.
 *
 */
public class SortAlgorithms {

private static char tracing;
private static char list;

private static int numAsgn = 0;
private static int numComp = 0;

private static int size;
private static int min;
private static int max;
private static final Scanner KBD = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.print("How many elements do you want in the list? ");
    size = KBD.nextInt();
    System.out.print("What are the smallest and largest values for lsit elements? ");
    min = KBD.nextInt();
    max = KBD.nextInt();

    KBD.nextLine();
    pause();

    System.out.print("Would you like to see the list before it's sorted? ");
    list = Character.toUpperCase(br.readLine().charAt(0));

    System.out.print("Would you like to see the list as it's being sorted? ");
    tracing = Character.toUpperCase(br.readLine().charAt(0));
    pause();

            sortNumbers();
}


// prompt the user and wait for them to press enter
private static void pause() {
    System.out.print("\n...Press enter...");
    KBD.nextLine();
    System.out.println();
}


  /**
 * Sort a list of integer values, generated randomly.
 */
public static void sortNumbers() {
    resetCounts();

    Integer[] numbers = randomNumbers(size, min, max);
    if (list == 'Y') {
        System.out.println("Here is the list: " + Arrays.toString(numbers));
        pause();
    }

    System.out.printf("\n%1s%25s%20s%20s\n", "Method", "#COMP", "#ASGN", "#OPS");

    bubbleSort(numbers);
    System.out.printf("%1s%25d%20d%20d\n", "Bubble", numComp, numAsgn, numAsgn + numComp);

    selectionSort(numbers);
    System.out.printf("%1s%22d%20d%20d\n", "Selection", numComp, numAsgn, numAsgn + numComp);

    insertionSort(numbers);
    System.out.printf("%1s%22d%20d%20d\n", "Insertion", numComp, numAsgn, numAsgn + numComp);

    shellSort(numbers);
    System.out.printf("%1s%26d%20d%20d\n", "Shell", numComp, numAsgn, numAsgn + numComp);
}

/**
 * Reset the operation counts to zero.
 */
public static void resetCounts() {
    numAsgn = 0;
    numComp = 0;
}

/**
 * Generate an array of random values.
 *
 * @param howMany the length of the list to be generated.
 * @param lo the smallest value allowed in the list
 * @param hi the largest value allowed in the list
 */
public static Integer[] randomNumbers(int size, int min, int max) {
    int range = max - min + 1;
    Integer[] result = new Integer[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        result[i] = (int) (min + range * Math.random());
    }
    return result;
}

/**
 * Perform bubble sort on the given array.
 *
 * @param a the array to sort.
 */
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>>
        void bubbleSort(T[] a) {
    for (int i = a.length - 1; i > 0; --i) {
        boolean elementSwapped = false;
        //numComp++;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
            numComp++;
            if (a[j].compareTo(a[j + 1]) > 0) {
                numAsgn += 3;
                T temp = a[j + 1];
                a[j + 1] = a[j];
                a[j] = temp;
                elementSwapped = true;
            }
        }
        if (!elementSwapped) {
            break;
        }
        //if (tracing == 'Y') {
            System.out.println("one more bubbled up: "
                    + Arrays.toString(a));
        //}

    }
}

/**
 * Perform insertion sort on the given array.
 *
 * @param a the array to sort.
 */
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>>
        void insertionSort(T[] a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; ++i) {
        int p = i + 1;
        T temp = a[p];
        ++numAsgn;
        while (p > 0 && a[p - 1].compareTo(temp) > 0) {
            ++numComp;
            a[p] = a[p - 1];
            ++numAsgn;
            --p;
        }
        if (p > 0) {
            ++numComp; // count the last a[p-1] comparison
        }
        a[p] = temp;
        ++numAsgn;
        //if (tracing == 'Y') {
            System.out.println("one more inserted: " + Arrays.toString(a));
        //}
    }

}

/**
 * Perform selection sort on the given array. if tracing, show the array
 * after each selection round.
 *
 * @param a the array to sort
 */
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>>
        void selectionSort(T[] a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; ++i) {
        int p = i;
        ++numAsgn;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < a.length; ++j) {
            ++numComp;
            if (a[j].compareTo(a[p]) < 0) {
                p = j;
                ++numAsgn;
            }
        }
            T temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[p];
            a[p] = temp;
            ++numAsgn;

        //if (tracing == 'Y') {
            System.out.println("one more selected: " + Arrays.toString(a));
        //}
    }
}

/**
 * Perform shell sort on the given array.
 *
 * @param a the array to sort.
 */
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>>
        void shellSort(T[] a) {
    int gap = a.length / 2;
    ++numComp;
    while (gap >= 1) {

        if (gap % 2 == 0) {
            ++gap;
        }
        ++numComp;
        for (int i = gap; i < a.length; ++i) {
            ++numAsgn;
            int p = i;
            T temp = a[p];
            ++numComp;
            while (p >= gap && a[p - gap].compareTo(temp) > 0) {
                a[p] = a[p - gap];
                p -= gap;
                ++numAsgn;
            }
            a[p] = temp;
            ++numAsgn;
        }
        //if (tracing == 'Y') {
            System.out.println("...gap=" + gap + ": " + Arrays.toString(a));
       // }
        gap /= 2;

    }
}

/**
 * Calculate how many operations a list of the given length should take.
 *
 * @param numItems the number of elements in a list.
 * @return the number of operations expected (on average) to sort that list
 */
private static int expect(int numItems) {
    return (numItems * numItems + numItems) * 5 / 4;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding array `numbers` each time you sort, so since `bubbleSort` is the first sorting method, you only get to see that one. Each consecutive sorting method just operates on a sorted array. Also since you've defined your counts as member variables, you need to call `resetCounts()` right before each method to get a fresh count. Making a copy of the array before you pass it to each sorting method, and resetting the counts should fix this.

```
System.out.printf("\n%1s%25s%20s%20s\n", "Method", "#COMP", "#ASGN", "#OPS");

resetCounts();
bubbleSort(Arrays.copyOf(numbers, numbers.length));
System.out.printf("%1s%25d%20d%20d\n", "Bubble", numComp, numAsgn, numAsgn + numComp);

resetCounts();
selectionSort(Arrays.copyOf(numbers, numbers.length));
System.out.printf("%1s%22d%20d%20d\n", "Selection", numComp, numAsgn, numAsgn + numComp);

resetCounts();
insertionSort(Arrays.copyOf(numbers, numbers.length));
System.out.printf("%1s%22d%20d%20d\n", "Insertion", numComp, numAsgn, numAsgn + numComp);

resetCounts();
shellSort(numbers);
System.out.printf("%1s%26d%20d%20d\n", "Shell", numComp, numAsgn, numAsgn + numComp);
```

Comment: got it thanks, and I have reset counter for the numAsgn and numComp but it does't give the right result. Could you find the error.

Comment: @K.Ji your count of `nubAsgn` looks good to me, however the `numComp` in some of the methods you have `(p > 0 && a[p - 1].compareTo(temp) > 0)` and you are counting that as one comparison i.e. `++numComp`, I don't know if you want to count as 2, `numComp += 2`. Other than that it looks good to me.

Comment: @K.Ji you bet. Glad I could help!